# Modifying an existing column to a foreign key

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, foreign-keys, ddl

I have an oracle db which has no Foreign Keys, all table relations are handled by the software. For example, table `Customer` with columns `Customer.customercode`, `Customer.Name` where `customercode` is the primary key and table `Order` with columns `Order.ordercode` (PK), `Order.customercode` where `customercode` has no foreign key constraint. So far the application handles all transactions and takes care of all the table relations so that the data are consistent. I need to change this to a proper relational DB implementation, so I need to modify `Order.customercode` to be a FK from table `Customer`. Any sqlplus statement to do this without losing my data?

Comment: if all data is consistent then there is no problem, just `alter table order add constraint ord_cust_fk foreign key (customercode) references customer (customercode);` and you are done.  Hopefully there is already an index on `order.customercode` if not it is time to add one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Oracle, creating a foreign key would never lose any data, but it will fail if the data doesn't correspond to the new constraint. Assuming your data is OK, you can use an `alter table` statement:

```
ALTER TABLE order
ADD CONSTRAINT order_customer_fk FOREIGN KEY (customercode)
REFERENCES customer(customercode)
```